# How to search an expression in a file from a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script.
I need to look if "text" exists in the file and do something if it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to execute a command on all files containing the text, you can combine `grep` with `xargs`. For example, this would remove all files containing "yourtext":

```
grep -l "yourtext" * | xargs rm
```

To search a single file, use `if grep ...`

```
if grep -q "yourtext" yourfile ; then
  # Found
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following would do what you need.

```
grep -w "text" file > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   #Do something
else
   #Do something else
fi
```

Comment: I prefer `if [ $(grep -c "text" file) -gt 0 ]` but it the same thing.

Comment: Martin's approach (with `grep -q`) is both faster (doesn't search entire file, just up to the first match) and (IMHO) cleaner than either of these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

[grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) is your friend here

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `grep` inside the `if` statement, and you can use the `-q` flag to silence it.

```
if grep -q "text" file; then
    :
else
    :
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat <file> | grep <"text">` and check the return code with `test $?`

Check out the excellent:
[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 0):

just use the shell

```
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
   *text* ) 
        echo "do something here"
        ;;
   * )  echo "text not found"
  esac
done <"file"
```